# How can I close a jQuery Modal dialog with an iframe in it?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery modal dialog that loads a different page on an iframe.

The iframed page has a form in it and i'm trying to get it to close the jQuery modal dialog automatically after the user submitted the form.

Is that even possible?

Thanks,

LoadModal code (on first.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showModal(url) {
$(function() {


var $this = $(this);
var horizontalPadding = 30;
var verticalPadding = 30;
$('<iframe id="externalSite" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="externalSite" src="' + url + '" />').dialog({
 title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'Choose your location',
 autoOpen: true,
 width: 700,
 height: 700,
 modal: true,
 resizable: true,
 autoResize: true,
 overlay: {
  opacity: 0.5,
  background: "black"
 }

}).width(700 - horizontalPadding).height(700 - verticalPadding);            

});
}
</script>
<button onclick="showModal('/iframe.html');">Add</button>
```

iframe code (iframe.html)

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

after iframe form is submitted, I would like to close the dialog opened by first.html jQuery function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that means that you want to close the dialog from inside the iframe, you could try something like that

```
parent.$('#your-dialog-id').dialog('close');
```

if needed i can provide a complete example later...

Comment: Hey roman, that sounds great. But the code i'm using creates the div automatically so I don't know what's the id (I have edited my question to include my code). How do I apply your code to mine? thanks

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really help me in my program now.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution (the accepted one did not work in my case):

```
parent.$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you send an example or source code ?

If you can't , try put an achor with target="" attr.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the source code. The iframe that is being loaded has a form in it (form action=""). Once it's submitted, I would like to close down the modal dialog. How can I do it?

Comment: is there any hideModal() function for this plugin?